# web page and php connection

Tags: php, html, database

connection using php is possible but when I give an example ... databaza.php so the page does not go at all and when I give databaza.html (I mean it as a subpage)
so the page goes but in the part where the connection table should be errory

I would like the page to work but with the .php extension. because when I give the .html extension, the page goes but the connection to the database does not and vice versa
where can be the mistake?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGLfV.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Check naming of files, also mozilla firefox loads better for php files if making just php files to load. hope this helps.

Comment: the files have good names I've already checked.